# 3rd party software for burning lightscribe labels for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, lightscribe

The official lightscribe software is awful (in my opinion).

Are there any alternatives? (Windows 7)

Comment: Are you looking for Windows only software?

Comment: @Troggy - Good point, I should include my OS.

Answer (score 2):

**[Nero](http://www.nero.com/enu/index.html)** comes with a label designer of its own, supporting LightScribe and LabelFlash.

[image]

I'm not aware of any free alternatives, as these are proprietary technologies. There are most likely royalties to pay.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Nero is now offering a free version of Nero CoverDesigner, which is suppose to be able to print Lightscribe labels (that is what I used in the past).

You can download it here: http://www.nero.com/enu/downloads/
or more precisely: http://ftp6.nero.com/tools/Nero_CoverDesigner.zip

You still need the official Lightscribe System Software drivers from: 
http://www.lightscribe.com/DownloadSection/windows/index.aspx

NOTE: I have not tried the current version myself yet because my Windows XP machine with the Lightscribe drive died in Superstorm Sandy and i am in the process of replacing it with a Windows 7 machine.